# incompatible dimensions in correlation test in the melanoma dataset

Tags: r, correlation

Im trying to find the correlation of age and thickness and its giving this message. age is integer and thickness numeric. I did the same with time and thickness and it worked fine. I don't understand what's wrong.

I tried with cor( age, thickness, method="pearson"), tried converting the age to numeric as well.Did not work.

Comment: U can check the data types using str(data), and try convert your data using data$age <- as.numeric(data$age), also check, if missing value is there, NA etc

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Guessing you're working in `data.table`.